# How can I fix my perceptron to recognize numbers?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, perceptron

My exercise is to train 10 perceptrons to recognize numbers (0 - 9). Each perceptron should learn a single digit. As training data, I've created 30 images (5x7 bmp). 3 variants per digit.

I've got a perceptron class:

```py
import numpy as np


def unit_step_func(x):
    return np.where(x > 0, 1, 0)


def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))


class Perceptron:
    def __init__(self, learning_rate=0.01, n_iters=1000):
        self.lr = learning_rate
        self.n_iters = n_iters
        self.activation_func = unit_step_func
        self.weights = None
        self.bias = None
        #self.best_weights = None
        #self.best_bias = None
        #self.best_error = float('inf')

    def fit(self, X, y):
        n_samples, n_features = X.shape

        self.weights = np.zeros(n_features)
        self.bias = 0

        #self.best_weights = self.weights.copy()
        #self.best_bias = self.bias

        for _ in range(self.n_iters):
            for x_i, y_i in zip(X, y):
                linear_output = np.dot(x_i, self.weights) + self.bias
                y_predicted = self.activation_func(linear_output)

                update = self.lr * (y_i - y_predicted)
                self.weights += update * x_i
                self.bias += update

            #current_error = np.mean(np.abs(y - self.predict(X)))
            #if current_error < self.best_error:
            #    self.best_weights = self.weights.copy()
            #    self.best_bias = self.bias
            #    self.best_error = current_error

    def predict(self, X):
        linear_output = np.dot(X, self.weights) + self.bias
        y_predicted = self.activation_func(linear_output)
        return y_predicted
```

I've tried both, `unit_step_func` and `sigmoid`, activation functions, and pocketing algorithm to see if there's any difference. I'm a noob, so I'm not sure if this is even implemented correctly.

This is how I train these perceptrons:

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from Perceptron import Perceptron
import os

def load_images_from_folder(folder, digit):
    images = []
    labels = []
    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        img = Image.open(os.path.join(folder, filename))
        if img is not None:
            images.append(np.array(img).flatten())
            label = 1 if filename.startswith(f"{digit}_") else 0
            labels.append(label)
    return np.array(images), np.array(labels)


digits_to_recognize = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

perceptrons = []
for digit_to_recognize in digits_to_recognize:
    X, y = load_images_from_folder("data", digit_to_recognize)
    p = Perceptron()
    p.fit(X, y)
    perceptrons.append(p)
```

in short:

training data filename is in the format `digit`_`variant`. As I said before, each digit has 3 variants,

so for digit `0` it is `0_0`, `0_1`, `0_2`,

for digit `1` it's: `1_0`, `1_1`, `1_2`,

and so on...

`load_images_from_folder` function loads 30 images and checks the name. If `digit` part of the name is the same as `digit` input then it appends `1` in labels, so that the perceptron knows that it's the desired digit.

I know that it'd be better to load these images once and save them in some array of `tuples`, for example, but I don't care about the performance right now (I won't care later either).

for digit `0` labels array is `[1, 1, 1, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`

for digit `1` labels array is `[0,0,0, 1, 1, 1, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`

and so on...

then I train 10 perceptrons using this data.

This exercise also requires to have some kind of GUI that allows me to draw a number. I've choosen `pygame`, I could use `pyQT`, it actually does not matter.

This is the code, you can skip it, it's not that important (except for `on_rec_button` function, but I'll address on it):

```py
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()

cols, rows = 5, 7
square_size = 50
width, height = cols * square_size, (rows + 2) * square_size
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Zad1")

rec_button_color = (0, 255, 0)
rec_button_rect = pygame.Rect(0, rows * square_size, width, square_size)

clear_button_color = (255, 255, 0)
clear_button_rect = pygame.Rect(0, (rows + 1) * square_size + 1, width, square_size)

mouse_pressed = False

drawing_matrix = np.zeros((rows, cols), dtype=int)


def color_square(x, y):
    col = x // square_size
    row = y // square_size

    if 0 <= row < rows and 0 <= col < cols:
        drawing_matrix[row, col] = 1


def draw_button(color, rect):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, rect)


def on_rec_button():
    np_array_representation = drawing_matrix.flatten()

    for digit_to_recognize in digits_to_recognize:
        p = perceptrons[digit_to_recognize]
        predicted_number = p.predict(np_array_representation)
        if predicted_number == digit_to_recognize:
            print(f"Image has been recognized as number {digit_to_recognize}")


def on_clear_button():
    drawing_matrix.fill(0)


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 3:
            mouse_pressed = True

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button == 3:
            mouse_pressed = False

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            mouse_x, mouse_y = event.pos
            if mouse_pressed:
                color_square(mouse_x, mouse_y)

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
            if rec_button_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                on_rec_button()
            if clear_button_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                on_clear_button()

    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            if drawing_matrix[i, j] == 1:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (j * square_size, i * square_size, square_size, square_size))
            else:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), (j * square_size, i * square_size, square_size, square_size))

    draw_button(rec_button_color, rec_button_rect)
    draw_button(clear_button_color, clear_button_rect)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

so, now that I run the app, draw the digit `3`, and click the green button that runs `on_rec_button` function, I expected to see `Image has been recognized as number 3`, but I get `Image has been recognized as number 0`.

This is what I draw:

[image]

These are training data:

[image]
[image]
[image]

These are very small because of the resolution `5x7` that was required in the exercise.

When I draw the digit `1` then I get 2 results:
`Image has been recognized as number 0`
`Image has been recognized as number 1`

[image]

What should I do to make it work the way I want? I don't expect this to work 100% accurate but I guess it could be better.

Comment: The derivative of the activation function is missing in the gradient computation.

Comment: The derivative of the activation func of the step function is 0, I believe, so the result will be always zero if I multiply `update = self.lr * (y_i - y_predicted)` with the derivative of this function

Comment: There's too much information we don't see here.  Are your training digits and your target digit bitmaps in the same format?  Is color an issue?

Comment: My training digits are loaded as an array of `0`s or `1`s. Same with the target digit. It's an array of `0`s or `1`s. It's either black or white (0 or 1). There's no 0 to 255 or 0.0f to 1.0f.

Comment: Can you share your training data?

Comment: @YakovDan I've added a few more training images: https://file.io/RmylRdMn1WKO. Now there are 11 variants per digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a few issues in the code, I will try to address them:

- It's missing the back progation function derivatives, as metioned in comments! Those are very important because they are the ones that guide the correction to the correct dirrection (based on the gradient).
- simillarly, the bias is not calculated correclty.

Here is a working code:

```
def sigmoid(x):
   return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

def sigmoid_derivative(x):
   return x * (1 - x)

class Perceptron:
    def __init__(self, learning_rate=0.01, n_iters=1000):
        self.lr = learning_rate
        self.n_iters = n_iters
        self.weights = None
        self.bias = None

    def fit(self, X, y):
        n_samples, n_features = X.shape
        self.bias = 0
        self.weights = np.zeros(n_features)
        for _ in range(self.n_iters):
            for x_i, y_i in zip(X, y):
                linear_output = np.dot(x_i, self.weights) + self.bias
                y_predicted = sigmoid(linear_output)
                
                error =  y_i - y_predicted
                
                output_error = error * sigmoid_derivative(y_predicted)
                
                self.weights += x_i.T.dot(output_error) * self.lr
                
                
                self.bias += np.sum(output_error, axis=0, keepdims=True) * self.lr

    def predict(self, X):
        linear_output = np.dot(X, self.weights) + self.bias
        y_predicted = sigmoid(linear_output)
        return y_predicted
```

As the main question is about the perceptron, I prefered to skip the `pygame` code. I used `from keras.datasets import mnist` to mock the images. The result correlate, given I didn't changed the Percetron class signature or main functionality. Here is the testing code:

```
from keras.datasets import mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()


train_images_resized = np.zeros((train_images.shape[0], 784))
test_images_resized = np.zeros((test_images.shape[0], 784))



for i in range(train_images.shape[0]):
    train_images_resized[i] = np.resize(train_images[i]/np.max(train_images[i]), 784).flatten()

for i in range(test_images.shape[0]):
    test_images_resized[i] = np.resize(test_images[i]/np.max(train_images[i]), 784).flatten()

desired_digit = 1

train_labels = [ 1 if label == desired_digit else 0 for label in train_labels]
test_labels = [ 1 if label == desired_digit else 0 for label in test_labels]


digits_to_recognize = [desired_digit]


X, y = train_images_resized,train_labels
p = Perceptron(learning_rate=0.05,n_iters=100000)
p.fit(X, y)
```

Note that I had to **normalize** (divide the the max value of each image) the input data so that the sigmoid function don't get saturated, making the derivative function = 0.

---

Results!

```
p.predict(test_images_resized)

array([0.004823, 0.531128, 0.94834 , 0.000155, 0.002682, 0.981524,
       0.008962, 0.067788, 0.017121, 0.00063 ])
```

```
test_labels

[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: I don't exactly get the `test_images_resized` and `test_labels` part. If I have only one test image (drawn by the user), how would you normalize it? Also if there's only one test image, thus test_labels is always just 1? Where are test_labels used?

Comment: mnist dataset has multiple labels, I filtered to test with only one in the answer (on local I tested multiple: `train_labels = [ 1 if label == 0 else 0 for label in train_labels]`). 

You can implement the normalization in the same way I did: in `load_images_from_folder("data", digit_to_recognize)`, on the line ` images.append(np.array(img).flatten())` , you can implement: ` images.append((np.array(img)/np.max(img)).flatten())` .This is just to reduce the values from the array to be between 0 and 1. 
On your solution you don't need to resize, you can ignore that part, as the images are 5x7.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing the usage of this perceptron. if my test image data is `[1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1]` (it is 0 from 5x7 matrix perspective) and I use this data in a loop for 10 perceptrons then the result of `predict` function should be `[closer to 1, closer to 0, ...,  closer to 0]` (first perceptron returns the value closer to 1.0, because it was trained to recognize digit 1 and the rest of perceptrons returns value closer to 0)?

Comment: If yes, then the first perceptron returns `1.1` and the perceptron number 8 returns `6.3`.   So there's clearly something wrong

Comment: As you will train 10 perceptrons, one for each number, 1 means it found the number in that part of the array. 0 means it didn't. It's a boolean true/false array, bottomline.

In you implementation: 
```
for digit 0 labels array is [1, 1, 1, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

for digit 1 labels array is [0,0,0, 1, 1, 1, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Comment: To clarify, you can completelly ignore the test part I implemented, the only code changes I did to you code was in the perceptron class .  The rest of the code should work fine, as long as the `img` array is between 0 and 1. Try it out

Comment: Just made a cuple fixes that I missed in the copy-paste process. Now it should make more sense. I'm trainning it to the digit 1, so it should return ~>0.5 to 1 when match and ~<0.5 to 0 when not match (it's usually much lower, like 0.05 when not match).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256241/discussion-between-vinicius-matos-and-shout).

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is in the `on_rec_button` function. The `p.predict(array_representation)` call will give you a number between 0 and 1, which is not comparable to `predicted_number`. Instead, for each `digit_to_recognize`, you should compute the `predict` outputs of all perceptrons, and take the final guess by the highest value, because you set the labels to 1 in the training sample for correctly recognizing a given digit. For that reason using `sigmoid` seems to me a better choice then `unit_step_func` to avoid dealing with ties.

Comment: Yes, I've already managed a few days ago that I should take the highest value.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in your training data, the value `1` indicates a background pixel and the value `0` indicates a digit pixel. But when you read input from the UI, you read the other way around: digit pixel is `1`, background pixel is `0`. I inverted the way you read the input such that it's consistent with the training data.

So, replace:

```
drawing_matrix = np.zeros((rows, cols), dtype=int)


def color_square(x, y):
    col = x // square_size
    row = y // square_size

    if 0 <= row < rows and 0 <= col < cols:
        drawing_matrix[row, col] = 1
```

with:

```
drawing_matrix = np.ones((rows, cols), dtype=int)


def color_square(x, y):
    col = x // square_size
    row = y // square_size

    if 0 <= row < rows and 0 <= col < cols:
        drawing_matrix[row, col] = 0
```

Comment: You're right. What a silly mistake...

Comment: Don't beat yourself up over it. It's hard to take a fresh look at your own work. Also, setting the digit pixel value to '1' is intuitive and standard practice.